# Exit the function/method if an exception occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I'm trying to find a code to exit the whole method if an exception occurs in a sub method. I tried adding return in catch section of Subfunction() but the process will continue to Thirdfunction()

```
 public static void Mainfunction()
    {
        try
        {
            //some code
            //some code
            Subfunction();
            ThirdFunction();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //write to log
        }
    }

    public static void Subfunction()
    {
        try
        {
            //some code
            //some code

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //write to log
        }
    }
```

So basically if an error occured in the Subfuntion() I want to stop the process from the Mainfunction() without continuing to the ThirdFunction(). Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: remove try/catch from Subfunction

Comment: If this is simplyfied and you MUST catch in the subfunction, you can rethrow ( just use `throw;` in catch block). But it's more efficient to just let it bubble up.

Comment: @Fildor Is that the only solution?

Comment: Basically, yes. Unless you make that `SubFunction` returns a value, and you check that value.

Comment: The only meaningful. Why do you even need a catch in `SubFunction`? If the answer is "just for logging" you could (and obviously already *do*) achieve this with a catch in `MainFunction`.

Comment: See my second comment. You can also wrap it in your custom exception and throw that. But again ... that's arguable.

Comment: Your two main options are to change `Subfunction` to return `bool` rather than `void` (and use an `if` in `Mainfunction`) or bubble up the exception. The latter is generally preferred.

Comment: I have been assuming you don't want to change the signature and return some sort of exit-code or "success-indicator". That would be the other options as pointed out by mjwills and Paul. But if I was given that task, I'd let it bubble.

Comment: A third possibilty would be a "state" object that you pass to the function on which you can set some property in case of an exception. But that is not much of a difference to a return value.

Comment: I wrote up an answer with a small collection of "solutions" to this problem. The obvious ones and some other crazy stuff that I wouldn't recommend but that I have actually seen in practice in C# and in Java (examples C#, only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two sets of possible solutions: With use of Exceptions and without.

With the use of exceptions, **I'd recommend to just let it bubble up** , as I've already said in comments.

Then you can rethrow:

```
try {
   // exception here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   throw;
   // Attention: this is _different_ from "throw ex" !!
}
```

Pay attention here:

> You can also use the `throw e` syntax in a catch block to instantiate a new exception that you pass on to the caller. **In this case, the stack trace of the original exception, which is available from the StackTrace property, *is not preserved*.**

See [throw (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw) (emphasis by me)

Coming over from Java myself, this is something people like myself will trip over during transitioning from Java to .Net. So if you got "java guys" new on the team: don't be harsh on them, just point them to the docs.

You can wrap:

```
try {
   // exception here
}
catch(Exception inner)
{
   throw new MyCustomException( "Some custom message", inner);
}
```

BTW: It is generally not a good idea to catch Exception. Most of the time you'd want to catch *specific* exceptions that you can actually handle.

---

The other class of solutions is without bubbling up exceptions:

Return value:

```
public static bool Subfunction()
{
    bool success = true;

    try
    {
        //some code
        //some code

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO write error log!
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Or with return or error codes:

```
// DO NOT USE MAGIC NUMBERS !
private static readonly int SUCCESS_INDICATOR = 0;
private static readonly int ERROR_INDICATOR = 1;

// TODO DOCUMENT which errorcodes can be expected and what they mean!
public static int Subfunction()
{
    int success = SUCCESS_INDICATOR;

    try
    {
        //some code
        //some code

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO write error log!
        success = ERROR_INDICATOR;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Especially with "C-Guys" on the team you may stumble across this one. (No offense - just my experience)

Or with a state object ...

```
public static void Mainfunction()
{
    try
    {
        //some code
        //some code
        ISuccessIndicator success = new ISIImplementation();
        Subfunction( success );
        if( !succes.HasException ) 
        {
            ThirdFunction();
        }
        else
        {
            // handle exception from Subfunction
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //write to log
        //Exceptions from ThrirdFunction or "else" branch are caught here.
    }
}


public static void Subfunction( ISuccessIndicator result )
{
    try
    {
        //some code
        //some code

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.HasException=true;
        result.Exception = ex;
    }
}


public interface ISuccessIndicator 
{
    Exception Exception {get; set;}
    bool HasException {get; set;}
}
```

And if you are really crazy you could ...

```
public static void Mainfunction()
{
    try
    {
        //some code
        //some code
        Exception ex = null;
        Subfunction( ref ex );
        if( ex == null ) // or more modern: ( ex is null )
        {
            ThirdFunction();
        }
        else
        {
            // handle exception from Subfunction
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //write to log
        //Exceptions from ThirdFunction or "else" branch caught here.
    }
}


public static void Subfunction( ref Exception outEx )
{
    try
    {
        //some code
        //some code

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        outEx = ex;
    }
}
```

Please mind, that I in no way would encourage using the latter. But it is *possible* ... and OP asked for possibilities.

Disclaimer: All snippets untested. Who finds errors can keep them (but please write a comment, so I can fix them).

Comment: A generic catch is extremely useful when calling a wonky third party DLL.

Comment: @JulieC As I wrote, _if you can_, catch specific exceptions that you can handle. Now your point is "wonky third party libs". True, if you have lacky documented API and you don't really know which exceptions could be thrown actually, you'd probably _at least_ want to log them regardless their type. But you need to understand that you need to make a distinction if this leaves you in a consistent state or not and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

> if an error occured in the Subfuntion() I want to stop the process
>   from the Mainfunction()

The simplest way to remove try/catch in your method `Subfunction`

If you want to keep the try/catch in this method, (for logging or something), rethrown exception

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {           
            Subfunction();
            Thirdfunction();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }    
    public static void Subfunction()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new AccessViolationException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```